# Really Bad Predictions while using LSTM (tensorflow)

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to fit a LSTM network on path-dependent input-output data (basically strains-stresses from elastoplastic behaviour). I took 14 different paths of input - output data and trained an LSTM Network , such that it gives sequence of outputs based on sequence of inputs.

I scaled the input and output data using MinMax Scaler like:

```
scaler_strains = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaler_stresses =MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

strain_scaler= scaler_strains.fit(train_strains)
stress_scaler= scaler_stresses.fit(train_stresses)

train_strains_norm = strain_scaler.transform(train_strains)
train_stresses_norm =stress_scaler.transform(train_stresses)
validation_strains_norm = strain_scaler.transform(validation_strains)
validation_stresses_norm=stress_scaler.transform(validation_stresses)
```

I also reshaped as (number_of_batches,number_of_time_steps,number_of_features)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(training_strains.shape[1:]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#Since number of output features is 6
model.add(Dense(6))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=opt,metrics=['mse'])
```

After training, even the prediction of validation set is very very wrong.

I tried:
1.Changing normalization limits since the input and output features contain negative values,but no use.
2.Didn't use any normalization, the losses were high and stagnant
3. Changed layers, (increased and decreased)  , but still no change.

I ran out of ideas...

Would be much obliged for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I'm afraid I have no idea what are "strains-stresses from elastoplastic behaviour" but unless they are very simple pieces of information with little variance, 14 pairs of sequences looks like an extremely low number of instances to train a model. My guess would be that the model can barely even start to generalize any information from the data. I might be totally wrong since I don't know the problem, but to me it looks like you need either much more data or to simplify the data massively.

Comment: @Erwan, thank you for the help. Basically, they are just inputs and outputs of a non-linear PDE at different time instants. I agree with you that data might be sparse. I will try with a large dataset.